# Laravel 5.2 PDO Exception on terminal

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, laravel-5

I am trying to recreate a downloaded site with Laravel 5.2 in my VPS and I am getting a PDO Exception when I run `php artisan` command on the terminal:

[image]

I checked that MySQL was installed with `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` and it has the latest version. I also sought in `phpinfo()` and I got the following information:

[image]

So, any clues?

Comment: You need to check that the PHP CLI also has PDO loaded. Do a `php -i` to find out which php.ini file the CLI loads and then check that php.ini

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have checked that as following: [Result here](https://i.imgur.com/ZNPOIfp.png)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP CLI often uses a different `php.ini` to the one used by the web server.

Do a `php -i | grep -i Loaded Configuration File`

Then check the `php.ini` file and if this line is commented with a `;` remove the `;` so the line looks like this

```
;extension php_pdo_mysql.so
```

Change to

```
extension php_pdo_mysql.so
```

This will activate the PDO extension

Comment: But there is no line such as that. The most likely line is `;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` and it has Windows extension

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: No, its a Plesk Server with Ubuntu 14.04, No one modified that file and PHP seems to be working fine despite the exception.

Comment: Did you check which `php -i` for `Loaded Configuration File` That is the ini file that the PHP CLI has loaded its config from

Comment: Yes, and that brought me to that directory: https://i.imgur.com/IDrIyMO.png

Comment: Better check your PATH or whatever its called in Ubuntu